# Android API7 clearing ongoing notification

Tags: android, notifications

from my service I send (with "ongoing" ID = 0) ongoing notification and it seems that there is no way of clearing it from code. if I send other notifications to the same ID (0), icon and intents
will update :/

I dont know if this is a bug in API 7 but it just dont make sens to me.

when I sent notification with Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE with different ID(ex. 1) then it is classified as simple notification and I could easily clear it from expanded menu or from code. BUT just by sending same notification to previous ID (0) it is classified as ongoing and I cannot cancel it anyhow!

I also tried to save reference to "ongoing" notification and then re-notify it with other PendingIntent and/or flags but it has no effect!

my current code of the service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "start notification");
    startStatusBarNotification();

    //do other stuff
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void startStatusBarNotification()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "startStatusBarNotification.");

    final int icon = R.drawable.stbar_icon_fail;
    final long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final Notification notification = new Notification(icon, getString(R.string.notify_title), when);

    final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getString(R.string.notify_title), expandText, contentIntent);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;//| Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR

    Log.d(TAG, "notify send.");
    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(SERVICE_ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);//ID = 0
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "clear status bar notification.");
    cancelNotification();

    super.onDestroy();
}

private void cancelNotification()
{
    final int icon = R.drawable.stbar_icon_exit;
    final long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final Notification notification = new Notification(icon, getString(R.string.notify_title), when);
    final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, null, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getString(R.string.notify_stopping_title), getString(R.string.notify_stopping_text), contentIntent);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.cancel(SERVICE_ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID);  //NOTHING HAPPENS
    mNotificationManager.notify(SERVICE_ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);   //ID = 0 but if this was changed to 1 cancel notification can be cleared :/
}
```

I can see "exit" icon so onDestroy and cancelNotification are called, i have no idea what im doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that you can successfully cancel ongoing notifications with ID 0: you will probably have to use a non-zero notification id.

The core notification manager service code is [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java;h=540389e21d84885da32b05b00231bd78f2951c7b;hb=HEAD), which doesn't appear to have a specific restriction on the choice of notification ID but everyone else who uses ONGOING notifications (for example, the Phone application) uses non-zero IDs.

Comment: well I tried and unfortunately this is not a case, actually I think this has something to do with threads as status bar runs in different thread/process than my service.

Comment: So when you use a non-zero ID for the ONGOING notification you still can't cancel?

Comment: I ve change it to 20;] I dont know really what Im doing wrong, can somebody confirm that you can cancel ongoing notification from service?

Comment: You realize that at the end of your `cancelNotification` function you are recreating the notification with `mNotificationManager.notify(SERVICE_ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);   //ID = 0 but if this was changed to 1 cancel notification can be cleared :/
`? If you remove that last line does it now work?

Comment: not nothing happens, the "old" notification stays, the odd things is that when I loop this cancel like 100 times before returning from cancelNotification eventually I got 2 notification - one "old" for running service and one from mNotificationManager.notify(SERVICE_ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification); which was normal notification